# how to make buttons from textview string

Tags: android, button, textview

How can i make buttons from the comma separated string in textview pragmatically .

```
TextView ingredient_txtview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recipe);

    String ingredients = ingredient_txtview.getText();

    String[] btnArray = ingredients.split(",");

    for(int i=0;i<btnArray.length;i++){
       // something 
    }
```

**Example:**

[Textview] "Button1, Button2, Button3"

**Result:**

[Button] Button1

[Button] Button2

[Button] Button3

Comment: You have String `"Button1, Button2, Button3"` and you would like to create (programmatically) 3 buttons?

Comment: Question with low quality are less likely to get a proper response. I'm missing your "what have you tried". Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: yeah, string is comma separated. so convert each word to button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to create layout (remember about `id` od root element):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

Next, you can use this layout in you Activity (example in Kotlin):

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.widget.Button
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var listOfButtons: MutableList<Button> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val input = "Button1, Button2, Button3"

        val split = input.split(", ")

        for (text in split) {
            val button = Button(this)

            button.text = text

            linear_layout.addView(button)

            listOfButtons.add(button)
        }
    }
}
```

And you can expect such output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Button> btns = new ArrayList();
for (String name: txtView.getText().split(",")){
    Button b = new Button(context);
    b.setText(name);
    btns.add(b);
}
```